# How to dynamically adjust an VS Code extension's main entry in package.json?

Tags: typescript, package.json, esbuild

My VS Code extension is bundled using esbuild and the generated `main.js` file is referenced in the `package.json` `main` property. This works fine.

For extension tests, however, I do the build using `tsc` and hence have to change the `main` property to reference the single `extension.js` file.

Changing that manually is obviously not a good solution and I wonder how to fix the test setup.

When I keep the `main.js` file then the extension host is launched with that and my tests cannot access most of the extension exports. For the extension tests I use `@vscode/test-electron` (in case this matters).

I could perhaps include my tests in the esbuild, but then I'd ship them with the extension, what I would like to avoid.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?